# What's the best way to determine a route's template based on $cookies value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like the root URL, `/`, of my AngularJS app to display a template based on cookie value. For example, when a login cookie is present display dashboard. When login cookie is absent, display a login screen.

I tried to inject $cookies to `app.config` to determine the template property of `$route` based on it, but that didn't work.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
myApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: function() {
                    // read cookies here?
                    return '../../connect.html';
                },
                controller: "getAuthUrl"
            });
        $locationProvider.
            html5Mode(true).
            hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

After further investigation, I found out that `$routeProvider` is not what I should be using. `$routeProvider` is for serving templates based on URL routes. What this problem needed is the [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) module, which is an official AngularJS module.

Instead of URLs, `ui-router` lets you specify page content based on "state". In my situation, I have a "loggedin" state and a "dashboard" state. Here's how I have implemented the solution:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.router']);

myApp.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider.
            state('login', {
                template: '<h1>Login now.</h1>'
            }).state('dashboard', {
                template: '<h1>You are logged in. Welcome.</h1>'
            });
        $locationProvider.
            html5Mode(true).
            hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);


myApp.controller('mainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$cookies',
    function($scope, $state, $cookies) {
        // You can read cookies here
        if (true) {
            console.log($cookies);
            $state.go('dashboard');
        }
        else {
            $state.go('login');
        }
    }
]);
```

And then the HTML is

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <script src='js/lib/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='js/lib/angular-ui-router.js'></script>
    <script src='js/lib/angular-cookies.js'></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='mainCtrl'>

<div class="container" ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can read all about `ui-router` in its [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

*Note:* You have to use `ui-router` v0.0.2 at least. v0.0.1 won't work.

Comment: UI-Router is awesome. Glad you found it. It should, however, be noted that you can accomplish the exact same thing by passing the $location service into a controller and using $location.path('/mypage')

Comment: @jimforcy `$location` wouldn't have worked. I want two different templates under one URL. I don't want to forward to another URL, eg `/mypage`.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Yes then UI-Router is exactly what you want.